# condition && command + exit

Tags: bash, shell-script

While writing a simple shell tool, I found a piece where I don't know how to get it to work.

```
  [ "$#" -ne 3 ] || echo "wrong number of arguments" && exit
```

The above works as intended because it's hard to conceive conditions where echo could fail. But what if I replaced echo with a command that can fail, and still execute `exit` nevertheless?

This won't work, because `exit` quits the shell spawned with `( )` and not the main one:

```
  [ "$#" -ne 3 ] && ( command ; exit )
```

This will exit always:

```
  [ "$#" -ne 3 ] && command ; exit
```

I could use the verbose syntax:

```
 if [ "$#" -ne 3 ] ; then 
      command 
      exit
 fi
```

but if I don't want to engage `if` and keep the syntax terse - how can I string conditional execution of commands, including `exit` like that?

Comment: There is more here:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/017?highlight=%28curly%29|%28braces%29

Comment: Are you entering an obfuscated shell code contest? If so you'll have to do better than that. If not, write what you mean: use `if`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can group command in curly braces:

```
[ "$#" -ne 3 ] || { command; exit; }
```

`{ list; }` causes lists command run in current shell context, not in subshell.

Read more about `bash` [Grouping commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
f() { [ "$#" -ne 3 ] && { command ; exit; }; }; f 1 2 3
```

Then

```
f() { [ "$#" -ne 3 ] && { command ; exit; }; }; f 1 2
```

Comment: what are 1 2 3  ?

Comment: Those are arguments passed to the function `f`. The  `{ command; exit ; }...`  runs only if there are less than number of arguments required.

Comment: @val0x00ff: `-ne` meaning not equal, not less than.

Comment: @Gnouc nice catch. It will indeed succeed only if there are 3 arguments passed, otherwise it fails.